In proof of Rabinowitch's trick ( Eisenbud, Commutative Algebra )
I am reading proof of Lemma 4.20 ( Rabinowitch's trick ) in the Eisenbud, Commutative Algebra and stuck at understanding some statement.

Lemma 4.20. Let $R$ be a ring. The following are equivalent :
a. $R$ is Jacobson ; i.e., every prime ideal is the intersection of maximal ideals.
b. If $P$ is  a prime of $R$ and if $S:=R/P$ contains an element $b \neq 0$ such that $S[b^{-1}]$ is a field then $S$ is a field.

Proof. b $\Rightarrow$ a : Let $Q$ be  a prime ideal of $R$, and let $I$ be the intersection of all the maximal ideals containing $Q$. We must show that $I =Q$. If, on the contrary, $I\neq Q$, choose an element $f\in I-Q$. By  Zorn's lemma we may choose a prime $P$ maximal among the primes of $R$ containing $Q$ but not containing $f$ ( How can we apply the Zorn's Lemma more concretely? ) By hypothesis, $P$ is not a  maximal ideal of $R$, so $S=R/P$ is not a field. Nevertheless, $P$ generates a maximal ideal of $R[f^{-1}]$, so $(R/P)[f^{-1}]$ is a field ( Localization commutes with quotient ) . This contradicts bypothesis b, so $I=Q$ as required. QED.
I don't understand the bold statement. Why $P[f^{-1}]$ is maximal ideal of $R[f^{-1}]$?  Can anyone explain why this is true more in detail?

Let $\mathfrak m \subset R[f^{-1}]$ be a maximal ideal which contains $P[f^{-1}]$. Then the preimage $\mathfrak n$ of $\mathfrak m$ in $R$ is a prime ideal which contains $P\supseteq Q$ but not $f$. By the maximality assumption on $P$ you get $P = \mathfrak n$, and so $P[f^{-1}] = \mathfrak m$.

Thanks !~ ^^ :)
